# How read line separated json file from azure data lake and query using usql

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-iot-sdk

I have ioT data in azure datalake structure as {date}/{month}/{day}/abbs. Json 
Each file has multiple records separated by new line ..
How to read this data using usql and load into table and query.

When I load it in usql table using /*/*/*/*.json will that load data into same table when new files added to files.

I have followed qzure docs but did not find any answer to line separated json file.

Comment: What azure docs have you read? And what is starting the u-sql query (so we can answer second part)

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.sqlchick.com/entries/2017/9/4/querying-multi-structured-json-files-with-u-sql-in-azure-data-lake%3fformat=amp.

Comment: https://www.taygan.co/blog/2018/01/06/azure-data-lake-series-working-with-json-part-1   I have read all three parts..  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f52be907-e5f9-4163-b400-0849480f9ff5/is-there-a-way-to-query-json-files-directly-from-data-lake?forum=AzureDataLake

Answer (score 2):

In this example we will create a table to store events:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Events  
(
     Event string
    ,INDEX cIX_EVENT CLUSTERED(Event ASC) DISTRIBUTED BY HASH(Event)
);
```

Then when it comes to extracting the json and inserting it into the database:

You first have to extract the lines using a simple text extractor, then you can parse it. For example, give a file with json objects separated with new lines

```
{ "Event": "One" }
{ "Event": "Tow" }
{ "Event":  "Three"}
```

then this script will extract the events:

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

@RawExtract = EXTRACT [RawString] string
    FROM @input
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter:'\b', quoting : false);

@ParsedJSONLines = SELECT JsonFunctions.JsonTuple([RawString]) AS JSONLine
    FROM @RawExtract;

INSERT INTO Events  
SELECT JSONLine["Event"] AS Event
FROM @ParsedJSONLines;
```

Later on you can read from the table like this:

```
@result =
    SELECT Event
    FROM Events;

OUTPUT @result
TO @output
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader : true, quoting : true);
```

Now, since it is an `INSERT IMTO` data will be appended to the table.

**Resources:**
[GitHub Examples](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/JSONExamples/JSONExamples)

[More GitHub Examples](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/JsonSample/JsonSample)